# Scraping a una tabla con BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-3.x, condiciones, beautifulsoup, scraping

Estoy tratando de raspar los dato de una tabla pero tengo problemas para hacerlo. He logrado raspar el 90% del contenido sin ningún problema, sin embargo en algunas paginas existe una tabla anidada que me esta haciendo la vida imposible.

Como si fuera poco debo crear una condición según se encuentre disponible o no dichas tablas... En caso de no aparecer la tabla existe una palabra que lo especifica, en el caso de estas paginas la palabra es "**Jogadores**", en caso contrario es una tabla con información.

### He aquí tres de esas páginas:

La [primera pagina](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Amazon_Helmet) en la seccion **Compra de:** y **Vende para:** especifica que el item se obtiene por medio de "**Jogadores.**", por lo tanto no hay que raspar ninguna tabla anidada en dicha pagina, pero sí debo raspar la palabra "**Jogadores.**" tanto de compra como de venta... cosa que ya había hecho pero decidí borrar y comenzar de nuevo, ya que cuando aparece una tabla en esa parte el raspado obtiene datos que no son los que necesito, y para ser honestos ya era mucho el rompedero de cabeza, así que borrón y cuenta nueva... mejor comenzar de nuevo que seguir en el enredo.

La [segunda pagina](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Bonelord_Helmet) en la sección **Compra de:** y **Vende para:** especifica que el item se obtiene por medio de "**Jogadores.**" pero se le vende a **NPCs**, por lo tanto requiero obtener el "**Jogadores.**" y también la tabla de **NPCs** *sin el encabezado*, solo el contenido.

Dado que todas las paginas que quiero raspar cumplen con el mismo formato (es una plantilla y son más de 7000 paginas), en algunos casos tanto **Compra de:** y **Vende para:** muestran una tabla cada una respectivamente de distintos tamaños. Eso significa que de algunas paginas debo raspar una, dos o ninguna tabla. He ahí mi idea del condicional, cuando no aparezca una tabla *entonces* obtén la palabra "**Jogadores**", en caso contrario obtén la tabla.

Por ejemplo esta [tercera pagina](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Steel_Helmet) contiene dos tablas anidadas en **Compra de:** y **Vende para:** que como ya saben también debo raspar.

### El codigo de mi programa:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[
    ('User-Agent', 
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/36.0.1941.0 #Safari/537.36'))]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Steel_Helmet')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

# ---------- OBTIENE ENLACE DE LA IMAGEN
table = soup.find_all('table')[2]
img_cell = table.find('td')
for img_link in img_cell:
    img = img_link.img['src']
    print(f'| img {" " * 14} = ' + 'https://www.tibiawiki.com.br' + img)

# ---------- OBTIENE NOMBRE
table = soup.find_all('table')[2]
name_cell = table.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling
span_uno = name_cell.find('span')
print(f'| name {" " * 13} = ' + span_uno.get_text().rstrip())

# ---------- OBTIENE EL GREEN TEXT
table = soup.find_all('table')[2]
flav_cell = table.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling
flavtxt = flav_cell.find('span').next_sibling
#print(f'| flavoredtext {" " * 5} = ' + flavtxt.get_text().rstrip())

# ---------- OBTIENE EL LOOT
table = soup.find_all('table')[2]
loot_row = table.find('tr').next_sibling
loot_cell = loot_row.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling
print(f'| loot {" " * 13} = ' + loot_cell.get_text().rstrip())

# ---------- VERSION DE IMPLEMENTACION
table = soup.find_all('table')[2]
vers_row = table.find('tr').next_sibling.next_sibling
vers_cell = vers_row.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling
print(f'| version {" " * 10} = ' + vers_cell.get_text().rstrip())

# ---------- NOTAS + SPOILER
table = soup.find_all('table')[2]
notes_row_one = table.find('tr').next_sibling.next_sibling
notes_row_two = notes_row_one.next_sibling
notes_cell = notes_row_two.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling
print(f'| notes {" " * 12} = ' + notes_cell.get_text().rstrip())

# ---------- VALOR MEDIO
table = soup.find_all('table')[2]
value_row_one = table.find('tr').next_sibling.next_sibling
value_row_two = value_row_one.next_sibling.next_sibling
value_row_tre = value_row_two.next_sibling
value_cell = value_row_tre.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling
print(f'| value {" " * 12} = ' + value_cell.get_text().rstrip())
```

Como pueden observar estoy raspando completamente cada pagina, con lo cual obtengo el `nombre`, una `descripción` de color verde, `loot`, `adicionado`, `notas` y `valor medio`, pero me falta `compra` y `venta`.

En ese codigo estoy raspando [esta pagina](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Steel_Helmet)...

### El código que me hizo doler la cabeza:

He aquí el fragmento que me trae loco desde que estoy con esto, creí haberlo desechado pero soy de los que les gusta respaldar algunas cosas para fines concretos.

```
table_vender = soup.find_all('table')[5]
table_vender_rows = table_vender.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_vender_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row_sell = [i.text for i in td]
    print(str(row_sell))
```

Ese pequeño fragmento me genera esto:

```
[]
['Shanar', "Ab'Dendriel", '293 gp']
['Memech', 'Ankrahmun', '293 gp']
['Cornelia', 'Carlin', '293 gp']
['Hireling (Trader)', 'Casas e Guildhalls', '293 gp']
['Azil', 'Darashia', '293 gp']
['Willard', 'Edron', '293 gp']
['Esrik', 'Farmine', '293 gp']
['Rock In A Hard Place', 'Gray Beach', '293 gp']
['Ulrik', 'Greenshore', '293 gp']
['Kroox', 'Kazordoon', '293 gp']
['Cedrik', 'Liberty Bay', '293 gp']
['H.L.', 'Outlaw Camp', '60 gp']
['Brengus', 'Port Hope', '293 gp']
['Flint', 'Rathleton', '293 gp']
['Robert', 'Svargrond', '293 gp']
['Gamel', 'Thais', '293 gp']
['Sam', 'Thais', '293 gp']
['Turvy', 'Thais', '293 gp']
['Hardek', 'Thais', '293 gp']
['Baltim', 'Tyrsung', '293 gp']
['Aldo', 'Venore', '293 gp']
['Yanni', 'Venore', '293 gp']
['Morpel', 'Yalahar', '293 gp']
```

Lo cual está muy bien, salvo por el primer `[]` vació . Este resultado representa la tabla de **Vende para:**, sin embargo falta el de **Compra de:**... ese fu el que borré.

Si agrego ese fragmeto al final de mi programa, todo irá de maravilla, hasta que intente raspar una pagina que solo diga "**Jogadores.**" en uno o ambos criterios de `compra` / `venta`.

### Lo que necesito:

Lo que necesito es básicamente lo siguiente:

1. Un condicional para raspar las secciones de `compra` / `venta` en caso de que aparezcan sus tablas o la palabra `Jogadores`.
2. Una mejora en el fragmento que obtiene la tabla (`compra` / `venta`) para que *no aparezca el primer elemento de la lista vacio* (`[]`).
3. Mostrar las tablas de `compra` / `venta` en caso de aparecer en alguna pagina o su condicional mostrando solo la palabra `Jogadores` según sea el caso.
4. De ser posible una explicación de lo que hagas, de verdad que sería el aporte más valioso para mi, un aprendiz de todo esto.

Dejaré por acá 4 paginas que cumplen todos los criterios posibles para `compra` / `venta` y su condicional segun sea el caso:

[Pagina 1 - Contiene tabla de compra y de venta](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Steel_Helmet)

[Pagina 2 - No contiene tabla de compra, pero sí de venta](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Bonelord_Helmet)

[Pagina 3 - No contiene tabla de compra ni de venta](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Amazon_Helmet)

[Pagina 4 - Contiene tabla de compra, pero no de venta](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Gill_Gugel)

**Nota:**  No pretendo que me hagan el programa, he dejado mi código para que veas más o menos como van los tiros y lo que llevo hecho. Con orientarme en el raspado de las tablas anidadas y la condición en caso de contener o no tablas en  `compra` / `venta` ya sería más que suficiente... aunque si puedes darme algunos tips para una mejora también son bienvenidos. De verdad que tratar de programar todo esto me ha embotado muchisimo y me ha confundido demasiado, por eso recurro al conocimientos de personas mas inteligentes en esto que yo.

De antemano muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer todo este testamento, se que es un poco largo, pero creo que está bien detallado.

Gracias nuevamente, aprecio tu ayuda. Un fuerte abrazo.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a tratar de ayudarte usando una estrategia *no recomendable*. Y espero que pueda ayudarte, al menos para que veas una forma de resolver tu planteo. Voy a utilizar el método `.select()` de `BeautifulSoup`. Lo cual funciona pasandole un selector, en este caso para acceder al selector de dicho elemento, nos vamos al elemento deseado, click derecho inspeccionar, una vez en el html nos dirigimos al tag deseado y le damos click derecho "`copy > copy selector`". De esa forma nos va a dar el selector css del elemento. Este *choclazo*, se utiliza cuando se encuentran elementos que no poseen clases para poder acceder a ellos.

Sin más vueltas, vamos al código:

Voy a definir una función y una lista con los dos selectores:

Primer elemento compra, segundo elemento vende.

```
selectores = ['#mw-content-text > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)',
             '#mw-content-text > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)']
```

La función `cargar_tabla` recibe el soup y el selector, va a llenar una lista de listas donde cada "fila" de la lista, será una row de la tabla.

```
def cargar_tabla(soup,selector):
    tabla_ = []
    tabla_jugadores = soup.select_one(selector)
                                       
    for a in tabla_jugadores.find_all('tr'):

        if a.find('td') is not None:
            npc = a.a.get('title')
            localizacion = a.find_all('a')[1].get('title')
            try:
                valor = a.find(class_='npcvalue').text
            except:
                valor = a.find(class_='exception').text
            tabla_.append([npc,localizacion,valor])
    return tabla_
```

Ahora solo falta llamar a la función, para eso, la tenemos que llamar dos veces para cada elemento de la lista `selectores`. Entonces vamos a iterar...
Al tener 3 urls, podemos hacer algo como esto:

```
urls = ['https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Bonelord_Helmet',
'https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Amazon_Helmet',
'https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Steel_Helmet']
```

Entonces ahora solo tenemos que hacer una petición para cada url.

```
result = []
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,'html.parser')
    select_result = []
    for selector in selectores:
        select_result.append(cargar_tabla(soup,selector))
        
    result.append([url,select_result])
```

Como verás en `result` se va a guardar el resultado de llamar a la función `cargar_tabla` y la `url` como origen de datos.
Ahora para mostrar los datos de una manera más elegante, voy a usar `pandas`:

```
for item in result:
    
    print('url :', item[0])
    for tabla in item[1]:
        display(pd.DataFrame(data=tabla,columns=["npc","localizacion","valor"]))
```

Salida: primero muestra para cada url: compra y vende

```
url : https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Bonelord_Helmet
npc    localizacion    valor
npc    localizacion    valor
0    Rashid    Gp    7 500 gp
1    Brengus    Port Hope    2 200 gp

url : https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Amazon_Helmet
npc    localizacion    valor
npc    localizacion    valor

url : https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Steel_Helmet
npc    localizacion    valor
0    Shanar    Ab'Dendriel    580 gp
1    Memech    Ankrahmun    580 gp
2    Cornelia    Carlin    580 gp
3    Hireling (Trader)    Casas    580 gp
4    Azil    Darashia    580 gp
5    Willard    Edron    580 gp
6    Esrik    Farmine    580 gp
7    Rock In A Hard Place    Gray Beach    580 gp
8    Ulrik    Greenshore    580 gp
9    Kroox    Kazordoon    580 gp
10    Cedrik    Liberty Bay    580 gp
11    Brengus    Port Hope    580 gp
12    Flint    Rathleton    580 gp
13    Robert    Svargrond    580 gp
14    Gamel    Thais    580 gp
15    Sam    Thais    580 gp
16    Turvy    Thais    580 gp
17    Hardek    Thais    580 gp
18    Baltim    Tyrsung    580 gp
19    Aldo    Venore    580 gp
20    Yanni    Venore    580 gp
21    Morpel    Yalahar    580 gp
npc    localizacion    valor
0    Shanar    Ab'Dendriel    293 gp
1    Memech    Ankrahmun    293 gp
2    Cornelia    Carlin    293 gp
3    Hireling (Trader)    Casas    293 gp
4    Azil    Darashia    293 gp
5    Willard    Edron    293 gp
6    Esrik    Farmine    293 gp
7    Rock In A Hard Place    Gray Beach    293 gp
8    Ulrik    Greenshore    293 gp
9    Kroox    Kazordoon    293 gp
10    Cedrik    Liberty Bay    293 gp
11    H.L.    Outlaw Camp    60 gp
12    Brengus    Port Hope    293 gp
13    Flint    Rathleton    293 gp
14    Robert    Svargrond    293 gp
15    Gamel    Thais    293 gp
16    Sam    Thais    293 gp
17    Turvy    Thais    293 gp
18    Hardek    Thais    293 gp
19    Baltim    Tyrsung    293 gp
20    Aldo    Venore    293 gp
21    Yanni    Venore    293 gp
22    Morpel    Yalahar    293 gp
```

pd: me faltó agregarle los headers a requests.get()
Espero que te sea útil